# How to present data from django-cms custom plugin in template

Tags: django, templates, plugins, django-cms

I have custom plugin with the next structure.
models.py looks like

```
    class ProductDescription(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        icon = models.ImageField(upload_to="installation_image", blank=True, null=True)
        description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

    class ProductPlugin(CMSPlugin):
            product = models.ForeignKey(ProductDescription)

    class ProductSpecification(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(ProductDescription)
        specification = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class InstallationStep(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(ProductDescription)
        step = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to="installation_image", blank=True, null=True)
```

admin.py

```
    class InstallationStepInline(admin.StackedInline):
        model = InstallationStep
        extra = 0

    class ProductSpecificationInline(admin.StackedInline):
        model = ProductSpecification
        extra = 0

    class DeviceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        inlines = [ProductSpecificationInline ,
        InstallationStepInline]

    admin.site.register(ProductDescription, DeviceAdmin)
```

and cms_plugin.py

```
    class CMSProductPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
        model = ProductPlugin
        name = _("Product Description")
        render_template = "product_description.html"

        def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
            context.update({
                'product':instance.product,
                'object':instance,
                'placeholder':placeholder
            })

            return context

    plugin_pool.register_plugin(CMSProductPlugin)
```

So, each product could have none or several specifications and installation steps. 
And the question is how can I render those specification and steps in template?
I know how to get data for the ProductDescription class. It is like

```
  <div class="test">{{ product.description }}</div>
```

but how can I extract other data? i guess it should be something like

```
    {% for steps in product.InstallationStep.all %}
        <div class="test">{{ steps.step }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
```

but it does not do anything =(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need:

```
product.InstallationStep_set.all
```

Since you have a ForeignKey in the InstallationStep model class, django puts the _set method into the referenced class.

You can experiment with this in the django shell. Templates will fail silently if you try doing foo.bar and there's no bar in foo...

Comment: Thanks man! You saved my day! Just one note, I had to use small letters like   product.installationstep_set.all

Answer (score 0):

According to [the doc](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html#for-foreign-key-relations-from-other-objects), you also need to modify the copy_relations method in the model. If not, the models won't be copied when you publish the draft and won't see anything. I don't understand how you manage to make it work.

In your case would be something like these:

```
class ProductPlugin(CMSPlugin):
    product = models.ForeignKey(ProductDescription)

    def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
        for associated_item in oldinstance.InstallationStep_set.all():
            # instance.pk = None; instance.pk.save() is the slightly odd but
            # standard Django way of copying a saved model instance
            associated_item.pk = None
            associated_item.plugin = self
            associated_item.save()
```

**NOTE**

Not sure about the `InstallationStep_set` on the for because I usually use the `related_name` parameter in the `ForeignKey` fields. For example,

```
class InstallationStep(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(ProductDescription, related_name='installationsteps')
```

and your for would be:

```
for associated_item in oldinstance.installationsteps.all():
```

In any case, thanks for the question because it became my guide.